# Why is this whitewash appearing whenever I click on an entry (email/password) for this flutter sign-up app?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[Image of the White wash popping up when I click on an entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bf0C.jpg)

I am using the [flutter login package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login) for the UI. I have no idea why this is happening and how I can debug it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Can you show your widget tree of the page? That would help us debug it better. The problem appears to be coming because of some padding values and/or the way you have defined your scaffold.

Comment: please share your source code so that we can take a look

Comment: Hey, nvm, it started working again for some reason. I guess it was just some temporary bug. Thanks though rishabh and beckzile